# applicationDidEnterBackground: is not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background-process, video-editing

I am creating a video editing app for iPhone.

When the user sets up the video editing and then starts the rendering, obviously it takes time.  When the user presses the home button, the application is minimized but the rendering still continues and `applicationDidEnterBackground:` is not getting called unless the rendering process finishes.

Comment: try applicationWillResignActive

Comment: I think they are both on the same thread. and the call back will be called only if cpu is free for very little time..

Comment: I have also try applicationWillResignActive but it is also not getting called...

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code that performs the rendering?

If it's a blocking call that takes a lot of time to complete and you are doing it in the main runloop, you are clogging up the run loop.  Your rendering code would need to finish before `applicationDidEnterBackground` would be called, and if this takes too long, iOS will simply kill your application instead.  IT would also freeze the UI, which you definitely don't want.

The most likely solution would be to move your rendering code to a background thread, but it really depends on what you are doing.